# Use of wildcards in firebase DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With a data structure like this one:

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Fred",
    "last": "Flintstone"
  }
  ,
  "personalId": "uniqueId-123132"
}
```

We can test for the existence of certain keys within a DataSnapshot using its exists() method:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users/fred");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var a = snapshot.exists();
  // a === true
  var b = snapshot.child("name").exists();
  // b === true
  var c = snapshot.child("name/first").exists();
  // c === true
  var d = snapshot.child("name/middle").exists();
  // d === false (because there is no "name/middle" child in the data snapshot)
});
```

My question is: Can we also test for the existence of certain keys without knowing the parent key using a wildcard like (*) ?

For example:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var d = snapshot.child("*/personald/uniqueId-123132").exists();
}
```